# Extra garbage values outside dimensions char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I have a 2 dimensional char array `char** field`. I have a method `get_field()` which makes a copy of this char array and returns this copy.

```
char** Game::get_field() {
    char** copy = new char*[this->width_field];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->width_field; i++)
        copy[i] = new char[this->length_field];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->width_field; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->length_field; j++)
            copy[i][j] = this->field[i][j];
    }

    return copy;
}
```

When I output the values of the copy to the console I get some garbage values after each row. However each row of the char array does contain the '\0' character to mark the end of the string. After some investigation with the debugger I found out that in the `get_field()` method extra garbage values are added **outside the dimensions specified when declaring the array**. [image]

When `length_field` equals 52 I got 51 dashes plus the '\0' character like in the image and after that some extra garbage values. Where do these garbage values come from and how do I get rid of them?

[EDIT:]
This is the code that does the output to the console:

```
char** field = game->get_field();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        cout << field[i] << endl;
    }
```

This is the code how the initial field is setup:

```
this->field = new  char*[this->width_field];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->width_field; i++)
        this->field[i] = new char[this->length_field];


    this->setup_field();


void Game::setup_field(){
    this->field[0] =    "---------------------------------------------------\n\0";
    this->field[1] =    "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[2] =    "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[3] =    "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[4] =    "|----                    |                    ----|\n\0";
    this->field[5] =    "|    |                  -|-                  |    |\n\0";
    this->field[6] =    "|    |                |  |  |                |    |\n\0";
    this->field[7] =    "|    |                  -|-                  |    |\n\0";
    this->field[8] =    "|----                    |                    ----|\n\0";
    this->field[9] =    "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[10] =   "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[11] =   "|                        |                        |\n\0";
    this->field[12] =   "---------------------------------------------------\n\0";
}
```

Comment: first thought is are length and width what you think they are?

Comment: Yes. Checked it with the debugger.

Comment: The interesting code is the one outputting your data to the console, (as well as that initializing it).

Comment: @Deduplicator added the code to the original post.

Comment: I'm sure you wanted to use `strcpy()` in `setup_field`, instead of discarding the newly allocated space (memory leak) and assigning the string literal in its stead. Where are `width_field` and `length_field` set?

Comment: width_field and length_field are set in the constructor of the Game class. I am sure they have the proper values, checked it with the debugger.

Comment: Those "correct values" are? Aside: String literals always end with an implicit `\0`.

Comment: `width_field` is 13 and `length_field` is 52. As you can see in the image in the original post I have 51 chars and then there is the garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the C++ standard nor the Microsoft implementation gives any guarantees about memory which does not belong to you.

Accessing it *for any reason* is undefined behavior => anything may happen.

If you hand a `char*` which does not point to a 0-terminated string to a function expecting one, it will access out-of-bounds memory until it finds a 0 or it crashs in some manner.
That should sufficiently explain your "added garbage".

Sidenote: Is there any reason you cannot allocate all needed memory in one chunk?

As you later added after prompting, your copied lines are **not 0-terminated**.
Full size of any line: length + 1: 51 printable + 1 newline + 1 terminator

Tip: If you cannot use `strdup` and / or `memdup`, define them for yourself.

Comment: That's the point. Every char* ends with a '\0' so I don't get it why after the '\0' and outside the dimensions of the array there is garbage added.

Comment: @tim_a Why are you even looking outside the dimensions of the array? Of course there will be garbage outside the dimensions of the array.

Comment: I am not. But when doing `cout << field[i] << endl;` the garbage is printed in the console. I get `length_field` characters and after that the garbage is added.

Comment: Please verify that `width_field` is 13 (#lines) and `length_field` is at least 53 (line-length including terminator: 51 dashes, 1 newline, 1 terminator).

Answer (score 2):

> When length_field equals 52 I got 51 dashes plus the '\0' character

You actually have 54 characters in your `Game::setup_field()` strings:

- 51 dashes
- One \n
- One \0
- One implicit \0 to end the string

Thus in your `Game::get_field()` method when you copy only 52 characters (stopping at the \n) you don't copy the \0 character resulting in an unterminated string.

Better to use a `vector<string>` or be more careful/explicit of array lengths when you initialize or copy things.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do it that way. Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> Game::get_field() {
    std::vector<std::string> copy(this->width_field);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->width_field; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->length_field; j++) {
            copy[i].push_back(this->field[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know working with STL containers and using std::string is much easier, but the code is part of an assignment which specially mentions that I have to work with a 2 dimensional char array.

Comment: Note that you are using a 2D char pointer array. A 2D char array would just be `char field[10][20]` which would be considerably simpler to work with.